# Convert string from text file to integer array

Tags: c#, file, integer

I wrote this code in order to open a text file in a C# language
Each line in the file contains five digits such as

```
0    0    2    3     6

0    1    4    4     7

0    2    6    9     9

1    0    8    11    9

1    1    12   15    11

2    2    12   17    15
```

The distance between the number and the other is one tab
The problem is when you execute the program this error appears

> input string was not in correct format  in Convert.ToInt32(t[j])

code:

```
string[] st = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\testing\\result.txt");
int[,] tmp = new int[st.Length - 1, 5];
for (int i = 1; i < st.Length; i++)
{

   string[] t = st[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
   int cnt = 0;
   for (int k = 0; k < t.Length; k++)
        if (t[k] != "")
           { t[cnt] = t[k]; cnt++; }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                tmp[i - 1, j] = Convert.ToInt32(t[j]);
 }
```

How can i correct that?

Comment: Hint: use braces everywhere. It'll make it a lot clearer. You currently *appear* to be under the impression that your second `for` loop is nested inside your first. It isn't.

Comment: The error 'input string was not in correct format in Convert.ToInt32(t[j])' appears when the input to `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't contain any number. How about setting a breakpoint there and checking the value of `t[j]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split `char` should be a *tab character* `'\t'` instead of single *space*

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko,@ Bhuban: Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I suggest changing the collection type from *2d array* `int[,]` into *jagged* one `int[][]` and then use *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 int[][] data = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\testing\result.txt")
   .Select(line => line
       // Uncomment this if you have empty lines to filter out:
       // .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) 
      .Split(new char[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
      .ToArray())
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have five numbers per row, but not necessarily five digits. You will need a more complex solution, like this:

```
string[] st = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\testing\\result.txt");
int[,] tmp = new int[st.Length - 1, 5];
bool isAlreadyNumber = false;
bool isEmptyRow = true;
int rowIndex = -1;
int colIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++) {
   isAlreadyNumber = false;
   isEmptyRow = true;
   foreach (char c in st[i]) {
      if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
          if (isAlreadyNumber) {
              tmp[rowIndex][colIndex] = tmp[rowIndex][colIndex] * 10 + (c - '0');
          } else {
              tmp[rowIndex][colIndex] = c - '0';
              if (isEmptyRow) rowIndex++;
              isEmptyRow = false;
              isAlreadyNumber = true;
          }
      } else {
          isAlreadyNumber = false;
      }
   }
 }
```

Note, that the indexing was fixed. This untested code handles other separators and empty lines as well, but still assumes there will be five numbers.